# Detect more than one language in same content with Google Translation API

Tags: javascript, php, google-cloud-platform, translation, google-translate

I am using a GCP translate API for checking language code for a content using language detect endpoint.

Statement: Content I am using for translation may have localization from two languages and I wish to detect both languages.

Problem: Confidence value return form endpoint also returns 100% if I mix content from another language in one paragraph.

Is there any way to detect if content only has one language or more than one ?

Example content:

**English:**

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
>   five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
>   remaining essentially unchanged.

**French:**

> Lorem Ipsum est simplement un faux texte de l'industrie de
>   l'impression et de la composition. Lorem Ipsum a été le texte factice
>   standard de l'industrie depuis les années 1500, quand une imprimante
>   inconnue a pris une galère de type et l'a brouillée pour faire un
>   livre de spécimen de type. Il a survécu non seulement cinq siècles,
>   mais aussi le saut dans la composition électronique, demeurant
>   essentiellement inchangé.

If I try to detect language it shows confidence of 100% due GCP localization algorithm.

Thanks in advance.